# Count elements of many lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have 10 lists and I want to know how many occurrences I have for each element.

Inputs:

```r
AAA AAA AAA
EEE III EEE
III DDD CCC
OOO OOO III
```

Output:

```r
AAA 3 
EEE 2
III 3
OOO 2
DDD 1
CCC 1
```

Comment: Perhaps `gather` and `count`? Are these `lists` or a `data.frame`(well, it's still a list)? Could you share perhaps two of your lists for a better idea what they look like?

Comment: Just use `table()`

Answer (score 4):

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="AAA AAA AAA
EEE III EEE
III DDD CCC
OOO OOO III")

table(unlist(df1))

 # AAA EEE III OOO DDD CCC 
 #   3   2   3   2   1   1
```

Comment: ***For a list of `data.farames`***: ```lapply(names(mylist), function(x) table(unlist(mylist[[x]]))) ```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is a `list` of `data.frame`s, with `tidyverse`, we can loop through the `list` using `map`, `gather` the dataset into 'long' format and `count` the 'value' column  (also the functions are commented by @NelsonGon)

```
library(tidyverse)
map(lst1, ~ .x %>% 
                 gather  %>%
                 count(value))
```

NOTE: The OP mentioned in the post about `Count elements of many lists`.